# Unable to install Ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 5577

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu in my Dell Inspiron 5577. It came with preloaded Windows.

I tried using Legacy mode as well with UEFI but it got stuck in Ubuntu logo when I start installing. Also tried by modifying `quiet splash` line to `nomodeset i915_bpo.nomodeset=1 quiet splash` referred from  [here](https://connorkuehl.github.io/dell-inspiron-7559-linux-guide/).

In this case it took me to the desktop screen, and I installed it but when I rebooted, it got stuck again while booting Ubuntu.